# Can't install zfcuser on Zend Framework 2

Tags: zend-framework, module, zend-framework2, zfcuser

I'm starting a new project, so I installed the skeleton zf2 project from github.
I followed the instruction provided here https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser, to install zfcuser.

I used composer to install zfcuser and changed the required files.

But although I can see the indexpage of the skeleton project at "`http://localhost/Test/public/`", when I go to "`http://localhost/Test/User`" all I see is default page saying

Not Found

The requested URL /Teste/public/user was not found on this server.

It's my first time installing modules on zf2. What am I missing?

Comment: Try this url - `http://localhost/Test/public/user` or `http://localhost/Test/public/User`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember: All requests will be served out of public/index.
That means if you set up a route like "/some/route" your current setup will have you go to `http://localhost/Test/public/some/route`

So the ZfcUser route will be: `http://localhost/Test/public/user`

If you can, try pointing your host root dir to /public.